# Making Depth First Search continue after first pass?

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I am trying to create a basic depth first search based web crawler. Here is my current code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class DepthFirstSpider {
    private List<String> visitedList; //web pages already visited
    private static String hrefExpr = "href\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]+)\"";
    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(hrefExpr);
    private int limit;
    private static Matcher matcher;
    private static URL contextURL;
    private static URL url;

    public List<String>  getVisitedList() { return visitedList; }

    //initialize the visitedlist and limit instance variables. Visit the starting url.
    public DepthFirstSpider(int limit, String startingURL) {
        visitedList = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.limit = limit;
        try {
            contextURL = new URL(startingURL);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        }

        visit(startingURL);
    }

    //print and add urlString to list of visited web pages 
    //create url and connect, read through html contents:
    //when href encountered create new url relative to the current url and visit it (if not already visited and limit not reached)
    public void visit(String urlString) {
        try{
            url = new URL(contextURL, urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String nextLine;
            while((nextLine=reader.readLine()) != null){
                matcher = pattern.matcher(nextLine);
                while(matcher.find() && limit > 0 && !visitedList.contains(url.toString())){
                    System.out.println("visiting " + url.toString());
                    visitedList.add(url.toString());
                    visit(matcher.group(1));
                    limit--;
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e){

        } catch (IOException e){

        }
    }
```

}

The search currently shoots down the tree of webpages without a problem. I need help making it go back up and then going to the pages it missed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I did a crawler, I used two queues instead of just one list. One queue contained the urls to visit and the other contained urls visited. I added all URLs I wanted to visit to the toVisit queue and as I visited those URLs I removed them from the toVisit queue(and added to the visited queue) and added all links on that page to the toVisit queue unless they were in the visited queue. There is no need to traverse in doing it this way.

Comment: I have a breadth first crawler that does just that. However I wish to use this particular search method here.

Comment: So you would use a stack instead of a queue for toVisit. After going as deep as possible, you would want to go to the next deepest sibling. Does that make sense? I would imagine you would still want to add hrefs as you encounter them as this would be easier than traversing part of the page and then traversing the rest of it later..

Comment: This makes sense, could you give an example though?

Comment: I also want to keep the recursive nature of the visit method.

Comment: so the way it is now, once you get in that nested while loop, while(matcher.find() && limit > 0 && !visitedList.contains(url.toString())) url.toString does not change. So this terminates at the deepest recursion level. You need to update url somewhere so it continues. i.e. this while will only execute once per recursive call.

Comment: That's what I had figured out and have been trying to work out. I'm trying to get that to work but can't figure out where to go back to in my visitedList so that it continues working.

Comment: Just update url. So either before or after the nested while loop or maybe even inside of it, url = new URL(contextURL, matcher.group(1)). But if at all possible, I would use a stack. Recursion gets expensive when crawling millions of webpages.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but,

in depth first, you need to keep track of the Expanded nodes as well. each generated child nodes you should add them to a stack (FILO) .

you should push() every expanded node to a stack and pop() at each iteration. when you reach the limit you will be poping upper nodes.

is this homework ?

you can find an ok explanation in pseudo-code in wikipedia.

Comment: Yes this is homework, how should I go about working the stack in?

Comment: Doesn't have to necessarily be a STACK, as long as you use your data structure in a First-In Last-Out manner.